# Given an algorithm with time complexity O(n^2), what happens if I triple the input n?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I got the following question wrong on a midterm a few months ago:

> Through experiment, you determine that **insertion sort** performs 2000 comparisons when sorting          an array of some size n. If you tripled the size of the array to 3n, approximately how many comparisons would it perform?
>
> A. 6000
>
> B. 12000
>
> C. 18000
>
> D. 36000
>
> E. It depends on the contents of the array

Given that insertion sort is O(n^2), I chose, C, 18000 and was marked wrong.

I reasoned it out this way: n^2 = 2000, => n =~ 44. 44*3 = 134, 134^2 = 18000

Which is the correct answer, and why?

Comment: It depends on the contents of the array. If it's already sorted, you'll have n-1 comparisons. If it's sorted in descending order, then you'll have a maximum amount of comparisons. I don't like this question very much, though, as I think that your reasoning is perfectly fine and a lot of people with good grasp of the subject are going to get this wrong.

Comment: Hmm. Does seem a bit hard to stomach. When I hear the phrase "by experiment" I'm picturing many different arrays as input, and a kind of implied average case scenario ... thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insertion sort is `O(n^2)` in the worst case and `O(n)` in the best case.

To insert a new element, insertion sort will search for the appropriate place for an element. If each new element the algorithm encounters is bigger than all the other ones (if you're sorting in ascending order), it will take only 1 comparison to find a new position for each new element.

So if the array is already sorted, the complexity will be `O(n)`, if it's sorted in reverse order, it will be `O(n^2)`.

So the correct answer is:

> E. It depends on the contents of the array